# What does type translation in SQLite3 gem do?

Tags: sql, ruby, rubygems

`type_translation = true` in the initialize method isn't documented on the gem's website. What does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer can be found by [examining the source code](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/blob/master/lib/sqlite3/database.rb#L123-L131):

```
# Return the type translator employed by this database instance. Each
# database instance has its own type translator; this allows for different
# type handlers to be installed in each instance without affecting other
# instances. Furthermore, the translators are instantiated lazily, so that
# if a database does not use type translation, it will not be burdened by
# the overhead of a useless type translator. (See the Translator class.)
```

And when you look at the [`Translator` class](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/blob/master/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb#L6-L9):

```
# The Translator class encapsulates the logic and callbacks necessary for
# converting string data to a value of some specified type. Every Database
# instance may have a Translator instance, in order to assist in type
# translation (Database#type_translation).
```

Therefore, when `type_translation = true`, sqlite3 will use that database's type translator to assist with serializing data between data types.

Answer (score 3):

From this link: https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/blob/master/lib/sqlite3/database.rb

"...The Database class provides type translation services as well, by which the SQLite3 data types (which are all represented as strings) may be converted into their corresponding types (as defined in the schemas for their tables). This translation only occurs when querying data from the database--insertions and updates are all still typeless..."

This may help too: https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html as it explains how data types are handled in sqlite3.